# Xcode/Swift cannot get any UI changes to work

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, xcode6

This is hard to explain, but every time I go to change a label or button's layout or property in the utilities pane, the changes I make wont be realized when I run the actual app. For example, I changed a label's alpha to 0.5, and the difference is noticeable in the app preview, but when I run the app the label has the same alpha as everything else ( ie 1.0 ). I am using NSTimers, and it almost seems that every time I go to press a button to reset the timer it resets the values of all the labels / buttons. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: paste your code. For UI, double check you don't recreate/assign the property to another UILabel or UIButton.

Comment: Try turning off AutoLayout in your Storyboard. That may fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be more specific please but i u should check your view higharchy and rearrange what u want first, etc.